# How to increment a column value in a table automatically without identity and primary key in SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which contains an unique ID column with value like "SLN000001",

I need to increment the column value whenever a new row added, but the column doesn't have identity and it's not primary Key.
How can I make it work?

Comment: Why not add IDENTITY and add the `SLN` and format in the selects?

Comment: I need to maintain 6 digits after "SLN", if I add identity some cases it got values differently with extra digit.

Comment: That can be managed with SQL string functions in the select - padding.

Comment: can you please send a sample function.

Comment: My name is also Munna.I think concatenating  formating identty column will not help because that is not your actual requrement.you hv to create UDF .Search in google like ' generate Alphanumeric ID in sql server "..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a computed column

```
CREATE TABLE #foo (
    IDColumn int  NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    PayLoad varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    TheRealKey AS CONCAT('SLN', RIGHT(CONCAT('00000', IDColumn), 6)) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY
    )
GO
INSERT #foo (PayLoad) VALUES ('Row 1'), ('Row 2')
GO
SELECT * FROM #foo f
```

Answer (score 2):

Use computed column

```
declare @test table(id int identity (1,1), 
       unique_no AS concat('SLN', right('00000'+ltrim(id), 6)), name varchar(100))
insert into @test(name)
select 'name1' union all select 'name2' union all select 'name3'
select * from @test
```